# Circle button has to be wrapped in a stackLayout CollectionView Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can someone tell me why when placing a circle button

(HeightRequest and WidthRequest same height  CornerRadius half the size)

in a collection you always have to wrap it with a stacklayout?

[image]

Code

```
<CollectionView >
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                             VerticalItemSpacing="10"
                             HorizontalItemSpacing="10" 
                             Span="3"  />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>1</x:String>
                <x:String>2</x:String>
                <x:String>3</x:String>
                <x:String>4</x:String>
                <x:String>5</x:String>
                <x:String>6</x:String>
                <x:String>7</x:String>
                <x:String>8</x:String>
                <x:String>9</x:String>
                <x:String>0</x:String>
                <x:String>Del</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button 
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        HeightRequest="60"
                        CornerRadius="30"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        BorderWidth="2"
                        BorderColor="Red"
                        Text="{Binding .}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, if you put `Button` in DataTemplate directly, `WidthRequest` or `HeightRequest` is not worked. The size of `Button` will be setted to the same as the parent control.

If xamarin forms render your layout in the Android platform at the end, `onMeasure` method will be executed.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

If we do not override the `onMeasure` method. The widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec which are the requirements passed to us by the parent.

If you want to know more details about `onMeasure` in Native Android, you can search "Android Custom View: mastering onMeasure" in Google.

To supported this conclusion, I set blue background of ``. Here is running screenshot.
[image]

If I removed the `CornerRadius="30"` and `StackLayout`. Here is running screenshot.
[image]

After comparing these two layouts, the result it same. If you want to add specific size of `Button` in a `CollectionView`, Please wrap a `stacklayout`.

Comment: thanks i just needed a confirmation that basically it needs to be wrapped up unless I override OnMeasure. Thanks for your time